# Forward declaration for classes called within method arguments of a protocol definition

Tags: ios, class, protocols, forward-declaration

Forward declarations are used to reduce dependencies and prevent unnecessary imports where multiple header files are involved.

This being said, how should I go about this scenario?

Let's say I have the following:

**ClassAlpha.h**

```
@interface ClassAlpha: NSObject

-(void)helloWorld;

@end
```

**ProtocolA.h**

```
@protocol ProtocolA <NSObject>

-(void)doSomethingWithAlpha:(ClassAlpha *__Nonnull)alpha;

@end
```

**ClassBeta.h (conforms to ProtocolA)**

```
@interface ClassBeta: NSObject<ProtocolA>

@end
```

**ClassBeta.m**

```
#import "ClassAlpha.h"

@implementation ClassBeta

-(void)doSomethingWithAlpha:(ClassAlpha *)alpha
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}
@end
```

In ProtocolA.h, should I use a forward declaration of ClassAlpha? However, if I were to do so, that would mean that ClassBeta would have to be the one that imports ClassAlpha within its implementation, alongside importing ProtocolA. Alternatively, if I were to use the import statement of ClassAlpha within ProtocolA, needless to say ClassBeta woudldn't need to do so. What would be the best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid `#import` in headers as much as possible. So, yes, you should use a forward declaration of `ClassAlpha` (i.e. `@class ClassAlpha;`) in `PrototolA.h`, because to use `ClassAlpha *` as a type in a parameter declaration, all you need to know is that `ClassAlpha` is the name of a class. You don't need to know anything else about how it is declared. Yes, you should import `ClassAlpha.h` in `ClassBeta.m`; you should do imports in implementation files as much as possible instead of header files.